# Deleting Objects in JavaScript. I'm a bit confused with JavaScript's delete operator

Tags: javascript, object

I'm a bit confused with JavaScript's delete operator.I am begginer in JS.  Take the following piece of code:

```js
function removeName (person){

   let user = {
       name : "name",
       surname: "surname"
   } ;
   console.log(delete user.name);

}
let x;
x = removeName();
console.log(x);
```

After this piece of code has been executed,I take as output true and undefinied, I take undefinied because I find it difficult to do object in function but true why? Please I am a beginner, so I think my code is miserable.

This confuses me, because I expected that writing delete user.name  would delete it and not just throw a true one.

Comment: `removeName` does not return anything, so it produces `undefined` by default.

Comment: @VLAZ I just forgot to write in (), and when I write I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the definition of removeName, you're expected to send a person.  You're currently not doing that, and you're placing the person inside the function too, and that would just end up scoping the person to this object.

So based on that info, this is how I assume you meant to write the code.

```js
let user = {
  name : "name",
  surname: "surname"
};

function removeName (person){
   delete person.name;
}

removeName(user);
console.log(user);
```

Comment: Basically I have an outbreak. If we do not write at the beginning let user = {
  name : "name",
  surname: "surname"
}; And let's start with function removeName (person) then how can it be done? for example to accept the person object as a parameter, and to
modifies the person object by deleting the property name field.

Answer (score 1):

[Delete returns true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#return_value). However you return nothing, so the function retuns `undefined`.

```js
let user = {
  name : "name",
  surname: "surname"
};
delete user.name
console.log(user);
```